# Unexpected contents display on the landing page while recording using JMeter with proxy enabled

Tags: jmeter

I used JMeter to record an ASP.Net application.

Most of the recording part are works perfectly fine. There is no error and the contents display correctly.

However, there are some test steps which cause the contents on the landing page to display incorrectly.

I turn off the proxy and execute the same test steps, there is no error and the content displays correctly. It happened for every browser; IE, Edge, Google chrome and Firefox.

Please help.

using JMeter 5.4.1.

Comment: Can you share screenshots of the issues? And your test plan as well if possible.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help without seeing:

1. This "unexpected contents" content
2. [JMeter log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)

The majority of recording problems are connected with:

1. Not importing JMeter's self-signed certificate into the browser, see **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) documentation for more details.
2. Custom authentication schemes like [NTLM or Kerberos, if this is the case you need to configure](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) HTTP Authorization Manager
3. It may also be a bug in JMeter, take a look at [JMeter Bugzilla](https://jmeter.apache.org/issues.html) and if it's not there yet you can raise a problem to JMeter developers.

In some cases it's much easier to use [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/) for recording, in this case you won't have to worry about proxies and certificates.

Comment: Thank you  Dmitri T. for taking time to help me out. The "Unexpected Contents": I cannot show you the content because the company policy. But I can give an example as follow: Here is the scenario of the recording steps: Login>>search for the customer name>>Click on one of the customer name on the list>>the "customer profile" page displayed on the landing page. (Done). but with the proxy enable, the "customer profile page did not display, instead, it displays the "customer registration" page.